# Display widget only on label search page in blogger/blogspot

Tags: javascript, html, blogger, blogspot

I want to display Blogger widget only on label pages. I search on Google, but haven't found any way to do it. How to do it?

Comment: this is not a programming question.

Comment: Raptor,can u tell me how you can do this without programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display widget in all label pages use this condition

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
  <!-- all label pages -->
</b:if>
```

To display widgets in a specific label page

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == "foo"'>
  <!-- for label 'foo' -->
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

For All Label's page your code will be:

`<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
<!-- HERE YOUR WIDGET CODE -->
</b:if>`

For Specific label's pae your code will be:

`<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == "ExampleLabel"'>
<!-- HERE YOUR WIDGET CODE -->
</b:if>`

your code widget code only run if all label page or specific label page.

Hope I will help you.
Waiting for your FeedBack.
Thanks :)